# Voice Over and touches?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, voiceover

I am creating an application based on gesture recognition. I would like to make it accessible, but I need to read a single touch (as well as double touches) when voiceOver is active. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning. Take a look at the [UIAccessibility Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html)